# How can I tell emacs how the arguments to my elisp function should be indented?

Tags: elisp, indentation, auto-indent

I have written function (actually a macro, but whatever) that works similarly to `progn`. How can I tell emacs that this function should be indented in the same way as `progn`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit. You want this kind of indentation inside the `emacs-lisp-mode`?

Comment: You want to properly indent and highlight the syntax, right?  It should work regardless of the construct (any s-expression should be properly indented).  Syntax highlighting is controlled by `font-lock-keywords`.  Can you post a screenshot of the "wrong" behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it

```
(put 'myfunc 'lisp-indent-function 0)
```

Documentation for `lisp-indent-function` (found by <kbd>C-h f lisp-indent-function RET</kbd>):

```
lisp-indent-function is a compiled Lisp function in `lisp-mode.el'.

(lisp-indent-function indent-point state)

This function is the normal value of the variable
`lisp-indent-function`. It is used when indenting a line within
a function call, to see if the called function says anything
special about how to indent the line.

indent-point is the position where the user typed TAB, or
equivalent. Point is located at the point to indent under
(for default indentation); state is the `parse-partial-sexp`
state for that position.

If the current line is in a call to a Lisp function which has
a non-nil property `lisp-indent-function`, that specifies how
to do the indentation.  The property value can be:

* `defun`, meaning indent `defun`-style;

* an integer N, meaning indent the first N arguments specially
  like ordinary function arguments and then indent any further
  arguments like a body;

* a function to call just as this function was called. If that
  function returns nil, that means it doesn't specify
  the indentation.

This function also returns nil meaning don't specify the
indentation.
```

Comment: Care to elaborate, or at least link to documentation?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I've found some time ago (and I don't remember where) a page describing how to fix emacs indentation for "if", "do" and and a few other common lisp constructs. From that page I decided to put in my .emacs a couple of those suggestions (now I've lisp-indent-function set to nil for "if" and to 2 for "do" and "do*").

I agree with you that the documentation for list-indent-function isn't that detailed.

Comment: Oops, maybe it would have worked the first time if I changed `myfunc` to the actual name of the function. I ended up going with `(put 'myfunc 'lisp-indent-function (get 'progn 'lisp-indent-function))`, i.e. "do whatever `progn` does."

Comment: @Ryan That's even better than the try-and-see approach I used

Answer (score 3):

As it's "actually a macro":

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Indenting Macros` <kbd>RET</kbd>

In this instance:

```el
(defmacro my-macro (&rest body)
  "Does things"
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(progn ,@body))

(my-macro
  (message "foo")
  (message "bar"))
```

Comment: Experimentally (Emacs 24.3) the `(declare (indent x))` form *does* also work with functions. I'd never tried that before. The byte compiler doesn't complain about it, so I guess it's okay to use. Interesting!